Advice for finding support to pass PhD milestone
I'm a 3rd year PhD student at a UK research university, but find myself scarily close to being forced to leave.
Who should I look for to help me resubmit my 3rd year milestone report?
Context: I have been working independently since last Autumn (I made a previous ASE post about this: trying to avoid being an orphan is harder than I expected). Still, I handed my notional supervisor my milestone report. He read through it and made suggestions to improve English and flow in places but otherwise said it read well and should be submitted for (internal) examination. I suggested an examiner who isn't in my subdepartment but would've been familiar with some of my techniques. Alas he shot me down, going for people he has known for years. I did a mock viva, and his feedback was just about being clearer what my work was vs others'. So from this, would it not be reasonable to conclude I had a reasonable chance to pass the internal assessment?
On the day, the interviewers started by saying they didn't understand my work. The whole interview was spent with me trying to go over fairly simple mathematics (I'm not doing anything that hardcore, honestly!). I wasn't asked on my subject area. I wasn't even asked about my PhD timelines and ideas for my final chapter (which are meant to be assessed).
So of course I failed that. I suppose I now have accepted that I have to communicate my ideas to these sorts of people.
My friends are theorists and other mathematicially inclined people, so they didn't struggle understanding my work but they seem a bad reference. Likewise with my supervisor, who is unfamiliar with my exact area of research. I clearly can't trust him now given the gap between his feedback and the examination.
So who should I find to help me figure out if I have written it right? Would experimentalist PhD student friends be enough of a resource? (The stakes are high now: fail again and I'm out)

What do you mean you "failed it"? Was that a formal assessment on your record or your general feelings about how you did?

The top answer on your referenced previous post strongly recommends that you need to find a real advisor, to avoid the pitfalls that come with lack of day to day supervision in your program. What steps have you taken towards this?

@Buffy no it was an official result, alas

@coffee_into_plots I joined a reading group of researchers, mostly from a university in the US, but I didn't feel it helped me to work on my exact problem. I suppose being forced to answer your question has made me realise that I haven't been so successful in finding people, or sticking with them. On the other hand I have also finished my project, so I'm more open to doing something different next. I'm currently on a summer research programme, and I have a supervisor here and it's pretty fun (they're pretty good). Just not my PhD field, unfortunately.

Hmm I can see that isn't a fantastic answer. If I may, I have some time before I rejoin my PhD programme (I'm doing another internship after this summer research programme), and I have been starting the ball rolling (by bringing it up with the graduate studies lead) on looking at joining a different group, or getting an external supervisor. Since I've finished my project, I am honestly open to joining a different group and hopefully being able to slot back into a more normal PhD life. I hope I can convince the relevant people that this is worth their time.

When you get such inquisitive people in juries I found that as a way out the best is to have published your work. Then you can always say "this work was published here and there...i was assuming the reviewers did their job...but one would certainly have to check the details".
This works because an unwritten rule in academia is that work published is "knowledge" so then it is not your job to answer detailed questions, but theirs to prove you are wrong. Or at least it can be understood that technical details are difficult to examine live.
Also, if you are able, do not let them choose all your reviewers. Try to negotiate finding someone that is external. If that someone has cited your work it is even better.
